Open a downloaded Word document in MS Word app
I am working on an iOS app where I need to download a .docx file and then open it in MS Word app if it's installed. I'm using .Net MAUI and C# for development.
First I'm downloading the document file bytes and saving it to a filePath. Then I'm using Office URI schemes to open the MS Word app and passing the saved filePath. MS Word app is launching successfully but there I encounter an error stating the file cannot be opened. I suspect this might be due to iOS sandboxing feature.
This is the code I'm using currently.
 var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
 var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(saveAsFilePath, downloadedFileBytes);

 var urlFilePath = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(saveAsFilePath);
 await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync($"ms-word:ofv|u|{urlFilePath}"); 


Is there any workaround or a different approach to achieve this?
I've checked that the path where the file bytes are saved is correct because I can use the same path to open the .docx file in a webView.

Could you use a structure similar to try-catch to see what error message comes out?

It is highly unlikely that you will be able to do this. The document is saved in your app's sandbox. Word cannot access that. You can prompt the user to save the file into the device files via the file picker interface and then they can probably go to word and open the file or you could try using a share sheet to allow them to share the file from your app to word.

@HugoJiménez The error "Can’t open file" is thrown in MS Word app itself. So, I can't catch that error from my code base.

@Paulw11 Ok. Thanks for your confirmation.

Can you see the downloaded .docx file in file app?
